# No module named 'openpyxl' - Python 3.8.2

Tags: python-3.x

I execute `pip install openpyxl`, but I still get 'No module named 'openpyxl' in jupyter notebook.

- pip install openpyxl

```
C:\Users\PeterFan>pip install openpyxl
Requirement already satisfied: openpyxl in c:\python38\lib\site-packages (3.0.5)
Requirement already satisfied: et-xmlfile in c:\python38\lib\site-packages (from openpyxl) (1.0.1)
Requirement already satisfied: jdcal in c:\python38\lib\site-packages (from openpyxl) (1.4.1)

C:\Users\PeterFan>python --version
Python 3.8.2
```

- I still have the error

> import openpyxl

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-16-f5ea1cbb6934> in <module>
----> 1 import openpyxl

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'openpyxl'
```

Comment: Welcome to [so]! ***Never*** post images of errors or code or anything that doesn't require an image and can be displayed in the form of text. It's easier for you to copy-paste it instead of screenshotting it, and easier for us to solve your problem.

Comment: You probably install multiple versions of Python. Try running `!pip install openpyxl` in the notebook.

Comment: I've tried `!pip install openpyxl` in my notebook, but the responses are the same as proceed `pip install openpyxl` in cmd. I have removed python 2.7 as well just now.

Comment: Do you use the virtualenv or else to manage your Python environment?  Or try `from openpyxl import WorkBook`.

Comment: Thank you for your kind response. I have resolved my issue. Very appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Thank you for your kind responses. I have resolved my question.

I installed multiple python versions(python 3.7.4, and python 3.8.2). I tried to `pip uninstall selenium`, `import selenium` in my notebook, and it still worked. Thus, I checked the document in the path `C:\Python38\Lib\site-packages` and there was no selenium package, but it exists in `C:\Python37\Lib\site-packages`.

I uninstalled python 3.8.2, deleting the environment variables pertaining to python 3.8.2., proceeding `pip3 install openpyxl`, the library was successfully installed and could be imported in my notebook.